# Detect zoom and done button with youtube-ios-player-helper on iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube

```
class testYoutubeViewController: UIViewController, YTPlayerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: YTPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.playerView.delegate = self
        let playerVars = ["playsinline": 0, "showinfo":0, "controls": 0, "autohide":1]
        playerView.load(withVideoId: "OsINvu5FYKg", playerVars: playerVars)

        //playerView.load(withVideoId: "M7lc1UVf-VE")
        //playerView.playVideo()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        playerView.playVideo()
    }

    func playerView(_ playerView: YTPlayerView, didChangeTo state: YTPlayerState) {
        switch state {
        case .playing:
            print("Stared Playback")
        case .paused:
            print("Paused")
        case .ended:
            print("Ended")
        case .buffering:
            print("buffering")
        case .unstarted:
            print("unstartd")
        case .queued:
            print("playing queued")
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView) {
        playerView.playVideo()
    }

}
```

*I wanted to add an observer to detect when the I press done or zoom on the youtube video player. 
*The video plays well and am able to control the play, pause, nextVideo, ..etc it well documented on https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#cuePlaylistObj. However I didn't see an Event example for detecting the done and zoom button.